# How to deploy a contract and its abstract/interface?

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, abstract

Assume I have a contract A:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract A{
  struct St{
    uint val;
  }
  function double(uint a)external returns (uint res){
  res= 2*a;
  }
}
```

Let's call the above lines of code **block 1**.

I deploy contract A. Then I have a contract B that wants to call a function of contract A:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract B{
   uint res;
   function call_double(uint val) {
   A a=A(0x1);// 0x1 is the address of contract A after it's deployed.
   res = a.double(val);
   }
 }
 // how to include this contract abstract when deploying contract B?
 contract A{
    function double(uint a)external returns (uint res);
    struct St{
    uint val;
   }
 }
```

Let's call the above lines of code **block 2**.

---

**Question**: How can I include contract A when I'm deploying contract B? In other words, how can I deploy block2?

Please note that when I'm using remix, (after I deploy contract A) I put both contract B and abstract of contract A in one page and deploy B, and everything works fine. But it's not clear to me how it's done when Im manually deploying to a private blockchain using web3. Also, it's not clear which ABI I need when I want to interact with contract B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance of contract A in contract B and then point that instance to the address of contract A.

Deploy contract A:

```
contract A{
  struct St{
    uint val;
  }
  function double(uint a)external returns (uint res){
  res= 2*a;
  }
}
```

Now when creating contract B, you can pass the address of contract A. Constructor of B will initialise the instance of A:

```
contract A{
     function double(uint a)external returns (uint res);
     struct St{
     uint val;
    }
 }

contract B{
    uint res;
    A objOfA;
    function B(address _addressOfContractA){
      objOfA = A(_addressOfContractA);
    }
    function call_double(uint val) {
      res = objOfA.double(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I did the same! I don't see any differences. in Block2, A a=A(0x1) is an instance of contract A.

Comment: my question is how to deploy the second part (i.e.  contract B and abstract of contract A) together.

Comment: You do not require to _deploy_ the abstract of contract A. When deploying B, you just need the abstract of A to tell B how to interact with A. In your block, A was written after B, which would fail to compile. Also, you used `var res` but it required `uint res`

Answer (score 0):

That's why the interface is needed.

Block2 must be look like below:

```
interface A{
     function double(uint a)external returns (uint res);
    }
 }

contract B{
    uint res;
    A objOfA;
    function B(address _addressOfContractA){
      objOfA = A(_addressOfContractA);
    }
    function call_double(uint val) {
      res = objOfA.double(val);
    }
}
```